# Figuring out how to incorporate functionality from another app into our own

Tags: architecture

Say I have two web apps which for the sake of simplicity I'll refer to as A and B. A is the primary app I work in and B is an entirely separate app with some overlapping logic/behavior/functionality. Application B was given to us by another group who was trying to do something pretty similar to what were doing.

Our goal: To pluck out the features we want from application B and add them to application A. 
The question: Do we put app B into an external service or API that app A can hit up, or, do we attempt to fully incorporate B into A.

The first option allows us to 'black-box' app A saving us a lot of time and trouble figuring out how the codebase works. On the other hand, the second option seems like the more architecturally 'proper' way of going about this. After all both apps have similar purposes/functionalities/etc so why separate them.

A significant portion of this issue breaks down into a matter of time versus quality so I realize no one will have a definitive solution for me. Rather, I'm hoping folks who've experience in similar situations might be able to provide some general consul or advice on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

If the application B can be used by any other application more than A, should be an independent application. On the contrary, should be a module or library, internal to the application A. It's my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the input. B will only be used by A so making it internal is what I'm leaning towards. One approach I've been contemplating is taking both paths. Starting off having B serve as an internal API (used only by A). This would allow us to have something to show for our work much sooner providing the appearance that the functionality has been moved over. This API would only be temporary though and from this point bits and pieces would be move over from B to A incrementally progressively phasing out the usage of the API.

Comment: I think the best option is that the application B is out of the application A. This promotes scalability of B. It is preventative. I think the best option is that the application B is out of the application A. This promotes scalability of B. It is preventative. You never know how long it will grow an application and those who will consume. Thanks you for vote my answer